# Neo4j for an Image database - performance considerations

Tags: graph, neo4j, nosql

I'm looking at building an image database which consists of nodes with a UUID field and other image properties such as EXIF data. I'll always search for image nodes via the UUID field which will have an index.

MATCH (img:Image {id: "ea191df3-f5e5-4a29-ae93-f850866f90d1"}) RETURN img;

Are there any performance disadvantages to doing this in Neo4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you create a uniqueness constraint via `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (image:Image) ASSERT image.id IS UNIQUE`, what you are proposing makes perfect sense.
Such a constraint not only enforces `id` uniqueness, but also creates an `id` index automatically.

There is a cost to updating the index every time you add an `Image` (or change an image `id`), but unless you have *many* more updates than searches, the savings when searching for an image should far exceed that cost.

Comment: I'd use a constraint instead of an index, `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (image:Image) ASEERT image.id IS UNIQUE`

Comment: @subvertallchris Thanks for the improvement. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Glad you caught my typo in `assert`. ;-)